# Add custom field with multidimentional array into solr search index

Tags: solr, drupal-7

based on this tutorial, I try to add custom field (with multidimentional array) into solr search index
http://msankhala.wordpress.com/2012/12/14/drupal-7-apache-solr-add-custom-field-to-solr-search-index/

I have array, let's call $array.

```
print_f($array);
Array
(
    [currency] => USD
    [rates] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [start] => 2006-11-29
                    [end] => 2007-11-05
                    [pricing] => Array
                        (
                            [monthly] => 7955
                            [anually] => 265000
                        )

                )

        )

    [tax] => 10
)
```

//hooking apache solr query

```
function search_engine_apachesolr_index_document_build(ApacheSolrDocument $document, $entity, $entity_type, $env_id) {
    $array= get_price($entity->nid);
    $document->setMultiValue('sm_price', $array);
}

function search_engine_apachesolr_query_prepare($query) {
    $query->addParam('fl', 'sm_price');
}
```

but ther result I got from solr only:

```
<arr name="sm_price">
    <str/>
</arr>
```

where's the content? why my array won't show up into the result?
I hope, I can get solution here :)

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Currently Solr doesn't support multidimensional array field. There are lot of discussions you can find in google on this. Even `multivalued` field in Solr gives you a simple array.

1. You can store your multidimensional array data as a string in a field (even in a multivalued field). Later you can parse it in your application.
2. Or you can design your multidimensional array in such a way, so that you can store it in the fields available in solr.

Comment: yeah after searching while, it seems impossible for now :-/. thanks